# How to add cron job in cpanel i want to run this command

Tags: cron, cpanel, jobs, cron-task

I want to add this command to run.

wget -O /dev/null http://alimoon.cf/wp-content/plugins/XYZ/auto.php

I have premium hosting but I don't know how to add this, here is my cpanel of cron jobs.

Thanks

Here is my cpanel of cron jobs.
http://i57.tinypic.com/2i94l5x.png

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server configuration is off-topic.

Comment: Better you should contact your host. It seems that there is a restriction to specify command for cron job.